# Check entered value's first character, if one of the conditions false, ask input again

Tags: c++, loops, input, char, iostream

Using c++;

I need to get input from user, then check the conditions (see below), if one of the conditions is false, ask user for input again (loop), using only `iostream` header.

Here are the conditions:

1. Input must be a letter (input cannot be a number, a word, a symbol)
2. Input must be "h" or "p" or "u" letter (input cannot be another letter and word like "ux", "xu" ,"uu", "hup")

I tried a lot but I failed

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char type;
    cout<<"enter type: ";
    cin>>type;

        while(cin.fail()==1){
        cout<<"error! invalid type. try again. \ntype:";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cin>>type;
    }

while(cin.fail()==0){
      switch (type) {
        case 'h':
        case 'u':
        case 'p':
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"error!invalid type. try again.\ntype: ";
                cin>>type;
        }
    }

    cout<<"valid type";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: could you please paste some code what you have coded till now?

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: You should post what code you've already tried, what is wrong, and what you expect to happen. The last of which you've done. As a tip you could try using `cin >> c` (c is a `char`). if you want to parse character by character. Or you can get the entire line the person entered using `getline(cin, str)` and parse that string.

Comment: i tried a lot of different codes (with while, for loops). now i posted the last one i tried

Comment: So if one of the condition is false the program will ask the user for another input and then the program have to check if the new input is fit to one of the two condition again?

Comment: yes. ask input again for valid (which input fits to two conditions) "type" input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "`type`s" are individual, space separated characters the easiest approach seems to be reading a string, verifying that it is just one character long, and that the character has an appropriate value, e.g.:

```
std::string tmp;
while (std::cin >> tmp
       && (tmp.size() != 1
           || (tmp[0] != 'h' && tmp[0] != 'u' && tmp[0] != 'p'))) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: invalid type try again\n";
}
if (!std::cin) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: reached the end of the stream before reading a valid type\n";
}
else {
    char type = tmp[0];
    // now do something...
}
```

Depending on you needs you might want to read an entire line (using `std::getline()`) instead of just one word.

Comment: thanks it worked. is there any other way to do it with only with iostream header (with no stream and no sstream header)

Comment: @sinyorcem: sure. Instead of reading a `std::string` you could read just one `char` and then check if the next character is a non-space. If so, you'd need to carry on reading after skipping all non-space character until a space is found (the spaces are then skipped when reading a `char`).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can use an array of characters. For example for an input with maximum 100 characters you can define the type variable like so:

```
char type[100];
```

This array will contain the ASCII code of the characters and after the last letter your elements will be `null` or `'\0'` if you use escape sequences. Your input will be a letter if its size is 1 and the first character is a letter. So declaring these simple functions your code will be clearer:

```
bool isOneCharacter(char* str)
{
    //check if the first character exists and the second one not
    return ((str[0]!='\0')&&(str[1]=='\0'));
}

bool isLetter(char ch)
{
    //check if a character is between ['a'-'z'] or ['A'-'Z']
    return (((ch>='a') && (ch<='z'))|| ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')));
}

bool isHUP(char ch)
{
    return ((ch=='h')||(ch=='u')||(ch == 'p'));
}
```

Knowing these things your main founction will be easy to write:

```
int main() {

    char type[100]; //input
    bool isOk; //it will be true only if the input fits the conditions

    do 
    {
        isOk = false; //initial value
        cout << "Type = ";
        cin >> type; 
        //note that the first space will be treat as the end of your input
        if (isOneCharacter(type)) //if type is a single character
        {
            //type contains a simple character at this point
            char charType = type[0];
            //if the input contains a single letter that is 'h', 'u' or 'p'
            if (isLetter(charType) && (isHUP(charType)))
            {
                isOk = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isOk)
        {
            //error message for the user
            cout << "Try again!" << endl;
        }
    } while (!isOk);
}
```

In this concrete situation you do not absolutely need to check if the input is letter, because if its value is 'h' 'u' or 'p' that autamically means its a letter. And if your input is a letter but not 'h' 'u' or 'p' the program above will ask the user for a new input without checking if it is a letter. But if you need to solve this problem by checking it I had written it for you.